# MS 365 Architecture and interdependencies between, SP online, MS teams and others in perspective of security and functionalities

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, team-sites, microsoft-teams, sp-online

We are migrating to MS 365 from 2010, I am new to this thing and was asked to prepare a proper architecture for the same, but as I am working I realized that msteams and other groups create their own site collections. So now I want to understand the architecture of this MS 365 and  between, SP online, MS teams and others in perspective of security and functionalities.

Because , I dont want MS teams to create site collections as well as I dont want people to share anything to any body, i wanted well administered and well controlled environment.

Please advice any links, courses etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far too broad to provide a succinct answer. You should pursue the [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/?view=o365-worldwide). If you have any specific questions that remain unanswered, create a new question, here.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is the storage platform for Teams.  Teams is basically a consolidator of various M365 resources, sharepoint, chat, email, meetings, planner...... the list goes on.  All files in a Team are stored in SharePoint so there is no way to have a Team without a Site collection to support the Team storage, a Team also creates a M365 group, and exchange mailbox.  Coming from SP2010 is going to be a big change, as Trevor stated above this is a huge topic to cover in a forum post.